# After importing the script, the bootstrap slider stops working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

After importing the script, the bootstrap slider stops working.
If I import this script:

```
<script src="http://echarts.baidu.com/build/dist/echarts.js"></script>
```

In console i have this error:

```
jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: r.easing[this.easing] is not a function
    at init.run (jquery.min.js:3)
    at i (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.r.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:3)
    at eb (jquery.min.js:3)
```

If I comment line with import script all is fine.

Comment: You need to include jQueryUI for the extended easing options.

Comment: I import this but nothing is better. I import this one: 
http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
I have to do something more than import ?

Comment: I use the function in css: transition to move the screen

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
i)Make sure you have imported jQueryUI which is needed for the extended easing options.

ii) put your Jquery Import on top of all the scripts

And in your Case: Put your `<script src="http://echarts.baidu.com/build/dist/echarts.js"></script>` on the bottom of all script